# Sharepoint forms-based to integrated authentication

Tags: iis, sharepoint-2007, fba

We have an existing Office SharePoint 2007 server farm doing out of the box NTLM integrated authentication.

Our web developer would like a landing page for external users using forms based authentication.

If we add FBA with the active directory provider then it appears we have to create duplicate user records inside of sharepoint (one for each authentication source).

Is there a program or service that maps FBA to NTLM without having to add the duplicate users?

Answer (score 0):

What we did was create a second URL for the FBA users, so users with NTLM-based credentials go to the original site and external users needing FBA go to this new URL. They both get served the same content, just with a different URL. I don't remember all the details off the top of my head, but I remember the biggie was creating an [Alternate Access Mapping](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288173(office.12).aspx) for the new URL.